# Generate Random Tuples Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, tuples

I was wondering if it's possible to generate random tuples with a code like:

```
take 4 $ randomRs ((0,0),(70,100)) $ mkStdGen x  :: [(Double,Double)]
```

when I try this one I get the error:

`No instance for (Random (Float, Float))       arising from a use of 'randoms'`

Is there a way to get random tuples without using `zip`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically the error message is saying that there isn't a defined way of making random tuples. But you can of course add one yourself.

Off the top of my head (i.e., I haven't actually tested this), you can do something like

```
instance (Random x, Random y) => Random (x, y) where
  randomR ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) gen1 =
    let (x, gen2) = randomR (x1, x2) gen1
        (y, gen3) = randomR (y1, y2) gen2
    in ((x, y), gen3)
```

Now you can use `randomR` on tuples (provided that the types *in* the tuple support random generation).

Comment: Drat! I was just about to post this answer! :) (Note you also need an instance for `random`, which is exactly the same as that of `randomR` but with only the `gen` argument.)

Comment: @dbaupp Yeah, I wasn't exactly sure off the top of my head which methods constitute the minimal definition for `Random`. IIRC there's about six or so methods in there...

Comment: how to implement the random method?

Comment: 'exactly the same as randomR but with only the gen argument' didn't work for me, perhaps related to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192126, "random = randomR ((minBound, minBound), (maxBound, maxBound))" *seems* to work, but I'm not 100% confident about this being the correct thing to do..

Answer (score 3):

You can use a state monad to generate random tuples conveniently:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State
import System.Random

randomTupleR ::
    (Random a, Random b, RandomGen g)
    => (a, a)
    -> (b, b)
    -> g
    -> ((a, b), g)
randomTupleR xb yb =
    runState (liftA2 (,) (state $ randomR xb) (state $ randomR yb))
```